# What is the meaning of the runtime error - internal CLR error 0x80131506

Tags: c#, .net, runtime-error, clr

While I was debugging a simple bit of C#. I got the error 'internal clr error 0x80131506' and the program being debugged crashed.  It's .NET Core 3.1 running on Windows 10 x64.

The code wasn't doing much interesting, just calling a method that iterates an array, from another static method in a class, ultimately called by a console application Main method.

I'd be interested to know if there is some way to look up these types of error codes, I couldn't find anything in my search - but perhaps I'm not searching for the correct thing, so any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: the first few hits on "internal CRL error" all share this code, and aren't obviously connected, so it looks to be something fairly generic; any direct repro code?

Comment: Ah, you think the code 0x80131506 is a general non-specific error, you're probably right.  I haven't been able to repro it unfortunately.

Comment: Anything in the event log for when this occurs?

Comment: The place you might get some hints is https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues

Comment: re: event log, I found this in Reliability Monitor; \Users\[me]\.nuget\packages\microsoft.testplatform.testhost\16.4.0\build\netcoreapp2.1\x64\testhost.exe stopped working, and I was debugging a test the last time I saw the error - so perhaps that's it.  No idea why testhost failed - but after seeing this I don' think the error is caused by anything in my code, so just going to ignore for now

Comment: In my case, my Home Page(Index page) was crashing with same error as mentioned in question and i checked the Home Controller and i found some issues there. So you can check your entire end to end controller.

Comment: A reboot of my PC fixed it in [my case](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/35435).

Answer (score -4):

After YEARS of using Unity, I finally got this error.
Similar to a lot of other weird and unexplainable errors.

When in doubt, reboot!

Deleted Library folder and rebuilt it - problem gone!

Comment: A reboot fixed it in [my case](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/35435), too.